# Aggregate information from one table to another with a different “layout” (mysql)

Tags: mysql

this is my starting table which provides sales information by Id.

| Id | Store_Name | Market | Sales | Main_Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | StoreA | Rome | 10 | a |
| 2 | StoreB | Rome | 15 | b |
| 3 | StoreC | Rome | 9 | c |
| 4 | Mag1 | Paris | 10 | a |
| 5 | Mag2 | Paris | 23 | b |
| 6 | Mag3 | Paris | 12 | c |
| 7 | Shop1 | London | 11 | a |
| 8 | Shop2 | London | 31 | b |
| 9 | Shop3 | London | 45 | c |
| 10 | Shop4 | London | 63 | d |

In order to build a report and create some dynamic sentences, I will need the dataset to be "paginated" as per below table:

| Id | Dimension | Dimension_Name | Sales | Main_Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ShoppingCentre | StoreA | 10 | a |
| 1 | Market | Rome | 34 | a |
| 2 | ShoppingCentre | StoreB | 15 | b |
| 2 | Maket | Rome | 34 | b |
| 3 | ShoppingCentre | StoreC | 9 | c |
| 3 | Market | Rome | 34 | c |

Do you have any tip about how to build the last table starting from the first one?

To sum-up:

- The new table will be always by Id
- Aggregation of market sales happens at row level where every single shopping centre is located

This is the query that I have built so far but wondering if there is a better and more efficient way to accomplish the same:

```
with store_temp_table as ( 
  select 
  id
  ,Store_Name
  ,Market
, Main_Product
, sum(Sales) as Sales
from Production_Table
where 1=1
group by
1,2,3,4
)
, market_temp_table as (
  select 
  market
, sum(Sales) as Sales
from Production_Table
where 1=1
group by
1
)
,  store_temp_table_refined as(
Select
 a.id
 ,a.Main_Product
 , 'ShoppingCentre' as Dimension_Name
 ,SUM(a.Sales) as Sales
  FROM store_temp_table a INNER JOIN
  market_temp_table b on a.market = b.market

group by
1,2,3
  )
 ,  market_temp_table_refined as (
   Select
 a.id
 ,a.Main_Product
 , 'Market' as DimensionName
  ,SUM(b.Sales) as Sales
    FROM store_temp_table a INNER JOIN
  market_temp_table b on a.market = b.market
group by
1,2,3
     )
   select * from store_temp_table_refined
   union all
   select * from market_temp_table_refined
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE that returns the dimensions that you want and cross join it to a query that returns the columns of the table and an additional column with the total sales of each market:

```
WITH Dimensions(id, Dimension) AS (VALUES 
  ROW(1, 'ShoppingCentre'), 
  ROW(2, 'Market')
)
SELECT p.Id, 
       d.Dimension,
       CASE d.id WHEN 1 THEN p.Store_Name ELSE p.Market END Dimension_Name, 
       CASE d.id WHEN 1 THEN p.Sales ELSE p.MarketSales END Sales,
       p.Main_Product
FROM Dimensions d 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT *, SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Market) AS MarketSales FROM Production_Table) p 
ORDER BY p.id, d.id;
```

Or, with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT Id,
       'ShoppingCentre' Dimension,
       Store_Name Dimension_Name, 
       Sales,   
       Main_Product
FROM Production_Table
UNION ALL
SELECT Id,
       'Market',
       Market, 
       SUM(Sales) OVER (PARTITION BY Market),   
       Main_Product
FROM Production_Table
ORDER BY Id, 
         CASE Dimension WHEN 'ShoppingCentre' THEN 1 WHEN 'Market' THEN 2 END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/QL8CZRGm).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The only problem with this approach is that apparently you can add in the 1st query a SUM(sales) which is actually what I would need.

Comment: @Kurt what do you mean by *problem*? The 1st query contains SUM() window function.

Comment: Hi @forpas, thank you again for your feedback. The 1st query generates a result which provides multiple rows for the Ids and the results generated by the Sales of the Market is not correct. The second one also generates incorrect results.  Of course the table that I shared is a test but it matches the original one which have many Ids.

Comment: @Kurt both queries return exactly your expected results which contain 2 rows for each id. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: @Kurt I provide a demo in my answer where you can check the results.

Comment: Thanks @forpas, I modified your demo at https://dbfiddle.uk/_9SDKtCO  to make the example closer to reality. We have several instances of the same store producing and this generates multiple rows for the same store which is not what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @Kurt why didn't you mention this in your question? Why did you post sample data that is not what you actually have. My answer is about the question as you posted it. If your requirement is different you should ask a new question.

Comment: I couldn't mention it before simply because I realized this problem later and not before when I originally asked the question